# How to create an HTML table with JQuery from an array of column values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

How to create an HTML table using JavaScript and JQuery from an array of column
values in arrays when the dimensions of the table are unknown and the number of cells is not the same in each column. Eg.

`[["1","4","7","10"],["2","5","8"],["3","6","9","11","12"]]`

Must become:

```
+----+----+----+
|  1 |  2 |  3 |
+----+----+----+
|  4 |  5 |  6 |
+----+----+----+
|  7 |  8 |  9 |
+----+----+----+
| 10 |    | 12 |
+----+----+----+
|    |    | 11 |
+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    var cols = [["1","4","7","10"],["2","5","8"],["3","6","9","11","12"]];
    var rows = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < cols.length; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < cols[y].length; x++ ) {
            if (rows.length < x + 1) {
                rows.push([]);
                while (rows[x].length < y + 1) {
                    rows[x].push("");
                }
            }
            rows[x][y] = cols[y][x];
        }
    }
    var table_elem = $("<table></table>");
    for (var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
        while (rows[x].length < cols.length) {
            rows[x].push("");
        }
        var row_elem = $("<tr></tr>");
        for (var y = 0; y < rows[x].length; y++) {
            var cell_elem = $("<td></td>");
            if (rows[x][y] != "") {
                cell_elem.text(rows[x][y]);
            } else {
                cell_elem.html("&nbsp;");
            }
            row_elem.append(cell_elem);
        }
        table_elem.append(row_elem);
    }
    $("body").append(table_elem);
});
```

Comment: I meant to answer. I spent a while wrestling with this so I thought I'd share it.

Comment: @PhistucK the reason he didn't already is because there's a 10 minute delay before you can accept an answer. Perhaps this delay is longer for self-answered questions even.

Comment: @PhistucK that's the plan! but it seems you have to wait 2 days to accept an answer that you've posted on your own question. Additionally although this solution is adequate for me, I'd be open to improvements and alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you like this one:

```
        var cols = [["1","4","7","10"],["2","5","8"],["3","6","9","11","12"]];

        function mkTable(cols) {
            var table = $("<table></table>");

            for(var y=0;;y++) {
                var row = $("<tr></tr>");
                var cols_left = 0;
                for(i in cols) {
                    var col = cols[i];
                    var date = $('<td>');
                    if(col.length > y) {
                        date.append(col[y]);
                        cols_left++;
                    }
                    row.append(date);
                }
                if(!cols_left)
                    break;
                table.append(row);
            }

            $('body').append(table);
        }
```